# php array any mysql problem

Tags: php

i have table called `config` contian `config_name` | `config_value`
know i want to extract it
like that

```
`config_name` | `config_value`
`articles_limit` | `10`
```

now i want php code give me an array like that
articles_limit => 10

Answer (score 1):

You might like to try using a database wrapper like [ADODb](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/), where such a thing would simply be

```
$config=$db->GetAssoc('select config_name, config_value from config');
```

As plain PHP, this would something like this

```
$config=array();
$result = mysql_query('select config_name, config_value from config'); 
if (!$result) 
{
    //handle error
    die(mysql_error());
}
else
{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $config[$row['config_name']] = $row['config_value'];
    }
    mysql_free_result($result);
}
```

Comment: well the usual way would be to use a wrapper rather than write all that!

Comment: New programs should use the mysqli extension.